# Submitting form displays title as body content?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

When submitting form on my website it should then display the Title and the body content however it seems to ignore the title and replace both with the body content ?
below attached is the code that's causing issue.
The DB has both fields name & body in place and is correct in the controller

This is the form for creating content -

```
<form  action="{{ route('document', $project->slug) }}" method="POST">
                <div class="add-form center-block">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="height:35px;" required="required" name="name" placeholder="Add document title">{{ old('document') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
        </div>
        <form  action="{{ route('document', $project->slug) }}" method="POST">    
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea id="summernote" name="document" required="required" placeholder="Craft your document here..."></textarea>
                <script>
                    $('#summernote').summernote({
                        height: 200, // set editor height
                        minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
                        maxHeight: 300, // set maximum height of editor
                        focus: true                  // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dash">
                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus"></i> create
            </button>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
```

And below is code that displays submitted content -

```
@foreach ($documents as $document)
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> {!! nl2br($document->name) !!}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {!! nl2br($document->body) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

JSfiddle with all code
https://jsfiddle.net/bnqt2u2r/

Comment: you write form action 2 times. remove the second one

Comment: do i wrap it in the one or just remove one and thats it ?

Comment: just remove second form action line. and provide information about $document. does it come from database or you just return it from Post request? Also you dont need to use foreach in this case.

Comment: ok i will try this thank you for quick reply :)

Comment: Secondly, your textarea name is document, but inside foreach you use $document->body.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use 2 different form instead of 1